# Consuming from a topic at a particular time during a day using spring-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We need to consume data from a particular topic at a specific time during a day, we want our kafka listener to be working only during that time of the day for the particular topic.

Was going through the article of Kafka Scheduler
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/kafka-KafkaScheduler.html

Any other approach or any help in using Kafka scheduler is apreciated.
We will be using spring kafka 1.3.10.RELEASE version

Comment: Do you want to consume from `beginning` or from `latest`? for the first you have to ensure the offset still exists(retention time).

Comment: we will keep auto commit to false so whenever we consumer say at a particular time, we will acknowledge that time so that from next day same time we start from the next offset on the same topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autowire the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` and call `start()/stop()` to start/stop all containers.

You can also use `registry.getListenerContainer("foo").start()` for starting a container with a specific `id`.

Set `autoStartup` to false on the containers so that Spring doesn't automatically start them during start up.

Comment: thanks @gary that was helpful, so we planning to start 2 schedule cron job one for starting the container and other one to stop it. kafkaListenerRegistry.getListenerContainer("kafkaErrorContainerFactory").stop(); kafkaListenerRegistry.getListenerContainer("kafkaErrorContainerFactory").start(); Anything else you see in this

Comment: Except you should set `autoStartup` to `false` and have some logic to test whether the application is being started in the "active" time and do a start there.

Comment: getting the null pointer error as the kafka listener bean name is not getting resolved

Comment: You should not ask new questions like this; ask a new question and reference this one if necessary. You need to set the`@KafkaListener.id` to something and use that in the `getListenerContainer()` method.

Comment: Can we use it with kafka-clients and KafkaConsumer?

Comment: Don't ask new questions on old answers. Can you use what? This answer is about using spring-kafka; if you are using the clients directly you can create and close the consumer whenever you want.